# Can weak convergence in $V$ imply strong convergence in $H$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the proof of the existence of strong solutions of the stationary NSE in the setting of Hilbert spaces, the following argument is made in Constantin and Foias's *Navier-Stokes Equations* (p60):

> Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n=2$ or $3$. Define
>   $
> V=\overline{\mathcal{V}}^{H_0^1(\Omega)^n}
> $
>   and
>   $
> H=\overline{\mathcal{V}}^{L^2(\Omega)^n}
> $
>   where
>   $$
> \mathcal{V}=\{f\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)^n\mid \textrm{div }f=0\}.
> $$
>   Let $u_m$ be a bounded sequence in $V$. Then there exists a subsequence $u_{m'}$ which is weakly convergent in $V$ to some $u\in V$. Passing to a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that $u_{m'}\to u$ in $H$ strongly.

Here is my **question**:

Why can weak convergence in $V$  imply strong convergence of a subsequence in $H$?

Comment: Isn't $V$ compactly embedded into $H$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that "weak convergence in $V$ *implies* strong convergence in $H$", but that [a compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator) maps bounded sets to relatively compact sets.

Once one knows that $V$ is [compactly embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_embedding) in $H$ (by the [Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem)), $u_{m'}$ has a strongly convergent subsequence in $H$ since it is bounded in $V$.